# How to check variable type in mako?

Tags: python, mako

I have a nested dict of dicts in a mako template and am trying to loop through them to print out their keys.

```
%for fruit in mydict['fruits']:
   ${fruit}
   % for nutrition in mydict['fruits'][fruit]:
      ${nutrition}
   % endfor
%endfor
```

The issue I am having is with the line:
"       % for nutrition in mydict['fruits'][fruit]:"

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

How can I check if mydict['fruits'][fruit] is a list or an int?

Comment: Is there a way in mako to check if an object is a dict or object?

Comment: Can you post your `mydict` data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, `mydict['fruits']` is a dictionary, and your `fruit` will be the keys. Indexing `mydict['fruits']` with `fruit` like `mydict['fruits'][fruit]` will result in getting the single item, which apparently, is an integer, and not a list of nutritions. Why it is an integer, is caused somewhere else in your code.

```
>>> for fruit in mydict['fruits']:
...   print fruit, mydict['fruits'][fruit]
...   for nutrition in mydict['fruits'][fruit]:
...     print nutrition
... 
kiwi 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

*Update*

(Confusingly, the question changed, and thus my answer needs updating.)

You could use `isinstance(mydict['fruits'][fruit], list)` and variants.

Or perhaps better, make sure things are always a list; i.e., put the type-checking logic in the Python code proper, and not in the template code. Because practically, why would an integer by a nutrient?

Also, consider simpler ways of iterating through a dict (assuming this works in mako):

```
>>> for fruit, nutritions in mydict['fruits'].items():
...     if isinstance(nutritions, list):
...        for nutrition in nutritions:
...            print nutrition
```